# Exibir valor de um item do objeto utilizando Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, array, objetos

Sou iniciante em Javascript, não sei como exibir o valor `qtdeEstoque` da `listaTamanhos`. Alguém pode me ajudar?

```
alert("Tamanho: " + lista.Value + " / Estoque: " + data[i].qtdeEstoque);
```

**listaTamanhos:**

```
id
qtdeEstoque
```

**Controller:**

```
if (HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
{
    return Json(new SelectList(
                listaTamanhos,
                "id",
                "id"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
                );
}
```

**View:**

```
$.getJSON("/produto", { id: id, cor: idSelected }, function (data) {
   $.each(data, function (i, lista) {
      alert("Tamanho: " + lista.Value + " / Estoque: " + data[i].qtdeEstoque);
   });
});
```

Comment: exibir onde? você ja tem alguma tabela e quer preencher ela? você quer criar um do zero?

Comment: Guilherme, eu gostaria de exibir a qtdeEstoque em uma mensagem JavaScript. Ela está em uma lista, já vem da tabela.

Comment: var listaTamanhos = tamanho.ListarTodosByProduto(id);    Eu não sei como acessar o atributo qtdeEstoque dessa lista em Javascript. Estou retornando via Json return Json(new SelectList(
                listaTamanhos,
                "id",
                "id"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
                );

Comment: Note que você esta com `(new SelectList(listaTamanhos, "id", "id"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` não seria `(new SelectList(listaTamanhos, "id", ` **"qtdeEstoque"** `), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`?

Comment: Você chegou a debugar e ver se existe `data[i].qtdeEstoque` porque pelo que você disse não.

Comment: não seria, retorno (new SelectList(listaTamanhos, "id", "id"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet), porque vou montar em html um select em html. E o ID é o value que é o mesmo da DESCRIÇÃO. Veja: <select id="tamanho" class="input-validation-error" data-val="true" data-val-required="Selecione o tamanho" name="tamanho">
<option value="">--Selecione o tamanho--</option>
<option value="35/36" >35/36</option>
<option value="37/38" >37/38</option>
<option value="39/40" >39/40</option>
</sel

Comment: preciso acessar o primeiro parâmetro do método SelectList(listaTamanhos, "id", "id")....listaTamanhos que tem o atributo qtdeEstoque

Comment: no Visual Studio não sei debugar o código Javascript, somente no Controller e na View códigos C#. Vi em debug que o atributo qtdeEstoque da listaTamanhos está sendo preenchida corretamente no Controller. Falta agora eu acessar no Javascript. Só que preciso naquele código que postei.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.getJSON("/produto", { id: id, cor: idSelected }, function (data) {
   $.each(data, function (i, lista) {
      alert("Tamanho: " + lista["id"]+ " / Estoque: " + lista["qtdeEstoque"];
   });
});
```

Comment: Pedro, fiz assim porém não funcionou. Retorna "undefined"..Agora, fazendo assim alert("Tamanho: " + lista.Value + " / Estoque: " + lista["qtdeEstoque"]); O tamanho retorna correto e o estoque "undefined"

Comment: Passa pra mim ai o json

Comment: var listaTamanhos = tamanho.ListarTodos(id);

if (HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
{
    return Json(new SelectList(
                    listaTamanhos,
                    "id",
                    "id"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
                    );
}